# How to su to www on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, su

I have a PHP script that I wish to run under the www account.

The account has nologin as shell and is used by Apache.

When I run "su -l www -s /bin/ksh" as root, I get the following message:

This account is currently not available.

I use OpenBSD 5.2

Comment: Does the account exist and is it unlocked and not expired?

Comment: Yes it is the account used by Apache, it has nologin as shell.

Answer (score 3):

www account is usually used for web server processes and direct login to shell is prohibited for security reasons. It is imperative it stays that way to prevent a hacking attempt on your website to get elevated rights on the server. just run

```
grep www /etc/passwd
```

and note the shell assigned to the account. It must be something like /bin/nologin or something to this sense. If you have root rights to this server, you can modify it but, I strongly suggest not to do such a thing. If you are just testing something, do it quickly and revert it back.

Of course this suggestion stands if you are running a public facing website on this server.

Comment: Indeed it has nologin as shell, I should have said that. I thought there was a way to su without touching to /etc/passwd content.

Comment: `su` does functionally mostly the same as `login` does - i.e. checks password and spawns user's shell of choice (login shell if invoked with `-l`, at least on Linux) etc. If shell is `nologin`, then all you get is the error message (printed by `nologin`).

Comment: I was trying to change the shell with the -s parameter.

Comment: if you have root privileges on this box and logged in as root, you can execute `usermod -s /bin/bash www` but if you are not root or don't have root access, you can not perform this action unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The simple option is to run your favorite shell as the user with a login shell behavior:

```
sudo -u www bash -l
```

Disadvantages of this:

1. It has subtle differences from an actual login.
2. It needs *sudo* as *su* uses the target user shell to exec the chosen shell.